# How to select all productnames where the unit price is greater than average unit price?

Tags: sql

I want to write a SQL statement which selects all the productnames from a database where the unit price is greater than the average unit price. I am required to write a subquery.

I tried it this way and I keep getting an error "from keyword not found where expected".

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCTID, Productname, unitprice
FROM 
    Products 
WHERE 
    unitprice IN (SELECT unitprice > AVG(unitprice) FROM Products);
```

Then I added parenthesis and I keep getting another error, "missing right parenthesis":

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCTID, Productname, unitprice
FROM 
    Products 
WHERE 
    unitprice IN (SELECT (unitprice >  AVG(unitprice)) FROM Products) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT PRODUCTID, Productname, unitprice
FROM Products 
WHERE unitprice > (SELECT AVG(unitprice) FROM Products)
```

Answer (score 0):

In almost any database, the best way is to use window functions;

```
SELECT PRODUCTID, Productname, unitprice
FROM (SELECT p.*, AVG(unitprice) OVER () as avg_up
      FROM Products p
     ) p
WHERE unitprice > avg_up;
```